# RStudio hang completely while building decision tree

Tags: r, rstudio

i'm new to R and just exploring of classification prediction now. I have a dataset contain of 4 columns, but up to 6600 thousand rows.

```
DATE   |TIME   |ITEM   |Job scope
Monday |12     |coffee |Police
Monday |13     |bread  |Police
Monday |22     |bread  |Medical
```

The job scope will become my class label, so at the end the prediction will be the job scope. For your information, the Item has 10 different variable and Job Scope has 5 different variables in the column.

I have tried with several algorithm like randomForest, rpart and cforest, but all seems like doesn't work and the RStudio will be freezed after the code has executed. Here's the code i use

```
fit <- cforest(as.factor(Job.Scope) ~ Date + Hour + Item,
               data = tt_10,
               controls=cforest_unbiased(ntree=2000,mtry=3))

fit <- randomForest(as.factor(Job.Scope) ~ Date + Hour +Item,
                    data=tt_10,
                    importance=TRUE,
                    ntree=2000)

fit <- rpart(Job.Scope ~ Date + Hour + Item, method="class", data=TrainData,
             control=rpart.control(minsplit=1))
```

Any suggestion towards the code or any guidance you could suggested to me will be much appreciated.

Comment: `ntree=2000` with roughly 10K observations seems like a fairly large calculation to me.  You probably only need at most 300-500 trees in the forest (or maybe even less than that).  Try the calculation with 300 trees and see if it finishes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi, i have reduced to 100 and finally it generate something out after awhile (around 15seconds), but it only works for cforest(). Do you have any idea why randomForest() will give this error to me [Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 53 categories.]??